# jqGrid searchOperator displays wrong operator after clearing the toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am now using jqGrid(version: jqGrid 4.14.1-pre, free jqGrid), with a column which have searchOperators.

The problem occurs when I clear the toolbar. My default operator is "<= (less or equal)". When I change the operator to other and clear the toolbar by x button of the column or the refresh button of navGrid, the searchOperator displays what I chose before, but filters as "<=", the default value. When I click the operator to show the drop-down popup, it highlights the default value, even though the display is different operator like below image.

[image: capture]

[This is demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) that I refered and it does not reset to the default value unlike my case. But I did not find any special difference between it and mine. (I don't think that custom searchOperator might matter.. does it?)
What I found was clearToolbar(), but it seems it only reset the textbox values.

I do not mind what kind of operator is left after the clear, but only thing I want is displaying the correct one. Could you please help me?

The following is the grid and toolbar codes.

```
tbLockedPartiesHistoryArea.jqGrid({
        url: '/LockedObjects/GetLockedParties',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'GET',
        emptyrecords: "There is no locked parties currently.",
        colModel: [
            {label: 'LockedBy',     name: 'LockedBy',       sorttype: 'text',   searchoptions: {clearSearch: true}},
            {label: 'LockedDate', name: 'LockedDate',   sorttype: 'date', searchoptions: {clearSearch: true},
                    sortable: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    hidden: false,
                    search: true,
                    formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A', newformat: 'm/d/Y h:i:s A'},
                    searchrules: {date: true},
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ["dle", "deq", "ge"],
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                                    var self = this;
                                    $(element).datepicker({
                                        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                                        changeYear: true,
                                        changeMonth: true,
                                        showButtonPanel: true,
                                        onSelect: function () {
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            self.triggerToolbar();
                                            }, 0);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                }
            }],
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 30, 50],
        prmNames: {
            page: 'defaultPageNumber',
            rows: 'rowsPerPage'
        },
        customSortOperations: {
            deq: {}, //I will just cut this since the code gets too long
            dle: {},
        },
        forceClientSorting: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        multiselect: true,
        multiPageSelection: false,
        pager: true,
        searching: {
            searchOperators: true,
            defaultSearch: 'cn',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            searchOnEnter: false,
            multipleSearch: true
        }
    });

    tbLockedPartiesHistoryArea.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
        ignoreCase: true,
        searchOperators: true,
        enableClear: false
    });
    tbLockedPartiesHistoryArea.jqGrid('navGrid', {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        refresh: true,
        refreshtext: "Clear Filter",
        refreshtitle: "Clear Filter"
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! The problem exist in case of usage `customSortOperations` (described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Custom-filtering-searching-Operation)).

I posted [the commit](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/a30bc5002a745cc81fe0fca5f7c49cf11807c444) just now. Please get the latest sources of free jqGrid from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). The problem should be solved now.

Comment: Hello, @Oleg ! I was worried whether I made any duplicate question, but it's my pleasure if my question was helpful. The bug has been fixed, and my grid works perfectly now. Thank you and have a good day! :)

Comment: @pebble: You are welcome! It was a new problem (no duplicate), which is fixed now. Have a nice day too!